# Javascript optimization, V8 engine and Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization, v8

I read the following article about V8 engine and javascript optimization.

[How JavaScript works: inside the V8 engine + 5 tips on how to write optimized code](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-inside-the-v8-engine-5-tips-on-how-to-write-optimized-code-ac089e62b12e)

According to above article, these are recommended :

a. V8 engine uses hidden classes and caching mechanism for the hidden classes and properties. So avoid dynamically adding object properties, and avoid dynamically changing the type of properties. Instead use object constructor function.

b. V8 engine applies more optimizations to frequently used functions. So avoid generating many different similar form functions executed only once. Instead write code to repeatedly execute same function.

Then, I have 3 questions :

i. Can 'a' and 'b' be applied to other browser's javascript engine, such as firefox's SpiderMonkey?

ii. According to 'a', using typescript is more advantageous for v8 engine optimization? (Using typescript, you can generate javascript code with fewer dynamically changing objects and properties)

iii. Modern JavaScript code uses a lot of inline and anonymous functions having similar form, like the example code below. According to 'b', using single predefined function is more advantageous instead? (This example code is very simplified one to show similar form functions used many times)

```
prm.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}).then((res2) => {
    console.log(res2);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: That example chain is going to log `undefined` for the second `then()` if the first `then()` is reached. I get your point though, multiple inline functions with the same implementation repeated are not A Good Thing.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts : Yes. The above code is very simplified example.

Comment: B) makes no sense. Write code that runs as often as it needs to. If it runs just once, speed doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Bergi I agree with your comment, but your comment does not help my question. This contradictory situation may be caused by my lack of English. Please read the article(linked in my question) and understand the intent of my question.

Comment: @pdh0710 Please [edit] your question to explain what you think is contradictory

Comment: @Bergi : What are you doing now? Are you insulting my lack of English now? I did my best to post my question.

Comment: @pdh0710 No, I'm not insulting you or your skills. I (and apparently a few others) just don't understand what you are asking, so can you describe in more/other words what is contradictory?

Comment: @Bergi : The contradictory situation is not in my question, but in " I agree with your comment, but your comment does not help my question". Do you mean that you did not understand this? How could you request me to edit my question? Did not you think that I did my best to post my question?

Comment: @pdh0710 Ah, I thought you were referring to some contradiction described in the question, not just that my comment doesn't (completely) answer your question. Erik's answer below should have everything you need, though.

Comment: @Bergi : O.K. I see. I'd already left comments on Eric's answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off your title is very weak.  Titles should be almost in the form of a question.  For example:  "Is it possible to optimize code for javascript engines?"

> Can 'a' and 'b' be applied to other browser's javascript engine, such as firefox's SpiderMonkey?

Sure, but that's up to the developers of those engines to do so.  I don't think asking it here has any benefit.

> According to 'a', using typescript is more advantageous for v8 engine optimization?

Typescript is compiled into Javascript.  V8 is a Javascript engine, so believing that the compiler for typescript is doing anything different for V8 OR V8 is doing any optimizations because it some how magically knows the Javascript came from Typescript, that any *advantageous* would be speculation at best (unless someone who is familiar with the code knows otherwise).

Since the TypeScript compiler is attempting to write good/optimized Javascript code anyway, V8 is simply taking advantage of good code.  Anyone can write good Javascript, it's just simply harder to write bad TypeScript.  But it's important to note that because Typescript compiles code the same way everytime, V8 can take advantage of that, but it's only beneficial if a programmer likes writing in Typescript.

> Modern JavaScript code uses a lot of inline and anonymous functions having similar form, like the example code below. According to 'b', using single predefined function is more advantageous instead?

Advantageous in what way?

Your anonymous functions are most likely already compiled out as `console.log()` is the only thing being called and could easily be in-lined.  So it's really a bad example.

As for functions that would be more complex, writing a single function is already a good principle to adhere to anyway ([Don't Repeat Yourself - DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).  So any programmer who keeps code DRY won't have any thing to really worry about because they've already written good code to begin with and subsequently V8 takes advantage of that.

Regardless of engine, it seems that the answer really is *just write good code*.

Comment: You understand my question too simple. Please consider that typescript generated javascript code has less dynamically changing objects and properties. And the above code is only a simplified example.

Comment: @phd0710 this still answers your question. Don't try to "optimize" your code. The engines are built to run the "regular" javascript as fast as possible. Just write "regular" code. It does not matter if that is typescript or not.

Comment: @pdh0710 If you had a better example, why did you not posted it? The answers are only as good as the question is. It's unclear what you mean by 'dynamically changing objects'. TS output is generally reasonable. Usually good code that avoids known pitfalls can be considered *reasonably* optimized. It isn't necessarily as fast as the fastest code you could write with raw JS - because TS tries to follow specs, this may result in some overhead.

Comment: @JonasW. :  In some ways, you are right. However, why the author of the article ('How JavaScript works: inside the V8 engine + 5 tips on how to write optimized code', link to the article included in my question) recommended those tips?

Comment: @estus : If you think my question is insufficient, please read the article ('How JavaScript works: inside the V8 engine + 5 tips on how to write optimized code', link to the article included in my question).

Comment: @pdh0710 why do you think that the article is contradicting this answer?

Comment: @JonasW. : Because you said "Don't try to optimize your code". However, the article recommends the optimization tips.

Comment: @pdh0710 I'm aware of this article and things that were discussed there and I think the question is insufficient. You haven't provided a detailed example that could be examined. *You understand my question too simple* - this is your responsibility to make the reader understand it the way you want. The question is based on your assumptions regarding TypeScript after reading the article. It would be helpful to elaborate what exactly you mean. Readers may be aware of things that are discussed in article, but the question should be fully understandable by reading only its content on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @estus : Please consider that I cannot satisfy everyone who reads my question. If you think my example code is insufficient, please do not consider my code, and focus on the article and my question.

Comment: @phd0710 *premature optimizations are the root of all evil*. Those fine grained performance tips only apply if you actually got performance problems. Otherwise they create more harm than good.

Comment: @JonasW. : I agree with you to some extent. My intention of the question is "If the tips recommended in the article are applicable to other browsers' javascript engine, the tips may be generally useful. Are they?"

Comment: @phd0710 yes they are mostly / probably / very likely.

Comment: @JonasW.: O.K. I understand. As Erik Philips pointed out, my question is related to some good programing principles. However, as everyone knows, even though there are good principles, the principles are not kept well, and the principles are not always good. So, it is necessary to understand why/when the principles are good and useful. I would appreciate if you think that this is the meaning of my question.